# nvm error downloading npm for previous versions

Tags: angular, npm, visual-studio-code, nvm

i use nvm for windows, i run nvm install in vs code terminal and then nvm use but then the command npm is not recognized for older versions, only for latest version of node. when i try to  install an older version of node i get a message:
Downloading node.js version 10.24.1 (64-bit)...
Complete
Downloading npm version 6.14.12... Error while downloading https://github.com/npm/cli/archive/v6.14.12.zip - Get "https://github.com/npm/cli/archive/v6.14.12.zip": net/http: TLS handshake timeout
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x20 pc=0xd8a5a7]

and then when i try to use npm -v
it says npm is not recognized.
only lts of node works well with npm and doesnt give any errors

Answer (score 0):

it was because of blocking of my organization, after they opened it to me i was able to download it